# Save and Load SVM in OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv, svm

I am training a model using a SVM and save it using:

```
svm.save("my_svm.xml")
```

When I try to load the model using

```
svm = cv2.ml.SVM_load('my_svm.xml')
```

I get the error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp:2203: error: (-212:Parsing error) Missing or invalid SVM type in function 'read_params
```

I checked the xml file and the field definitely exists under

```
<opencv_storage>
   <opencv_ml_svm>
      <format>3</format>
      <svmType>C_SVC</svmType>
       ....
```

I checked the file [online](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp) and it looks like this:

```
// check for old naming
String svm_type_str = (String)(fn["svm_type"].empty() ? fn["svmType"] : fn["svm_type"]);
int svmType =
    svm_type_str == "C_SVC" ? C_SVC :
    svm_type_str == "NU_SVC" ? NU_SVC :
    svm_type_str == "ONE_CLASS" ? ONE_CLASS :
    svm_type_str == "EPS_SVR" ? EPS_SVR :
    svm_type_str == "NU_SVR" ? NU_SVR : -1;

if( svmType < 0 )
    CV_Error( CV_StsParseError, "Missing or invalid SVM type" );
```

Does anybody have any ideas why it could fail?

Comment: Try to remove node "opencv_ml_svm" (opening and clode) from xml

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. Is this a known error? I tried loading it in C++ and it worked.

Comment: I see to the sources and to the your xml. And decide than this tag must be ignored. I'll create the PL to the OpenCV with this fix

Comment: I found this in `ml.cpp`: 
`String getDefaultName() const CV_OVERRIDE {return "opencv_ml_svm";}`

But it never seems to be called

Comment: Actually you don't need to remove the  node "opencv_ml_svm". I just have been searching the error at the wrong location the whole time. My path was incorrect and that is the error it returns when the `.xml` doesn't exist!